# Delphi detecting image type in TImageControl

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

I am trying to detect the image type loaded in FMX's `TImageControl`. I am using Delphi 10.3 Rio.

My code is as follows:

```
function DetectImage(BM: TBitmap): string;
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
  FirstBytes: AnsiString;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    BM.SaveToStream(MS);
    SetLength(FirstBytes, 8);
    MS.Read(FirstBytes[1], 8);
    if Copy(FirstBytes, 1, 2) = 'BM' then
    begin
      Result := 'bmp';
    end
    else if FirstBytes = #137'PNG'#13#10#26#10 then
    begin
      Result := 'png';
    end
    else if Copy(FirstBytes, 1, 3) = 'GIF' then
    begin
      Result := 'gif';
    end
    else if Copy(FirstBytes, 1, 2) = #$FF#$D8 then
    begin
      Result := 'jpg';
    end
    else
      Result := '?';

  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.imgTeamAChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ShowMessage(DetectImage(imgTeamA.Bitmap))  ;
end;
```

So, when I click on the `TImageControl` to change it, I always get '?' as a result.

How do I make this working?

Comment: Even if you made this work, surely you know what's in a bitmap. You need to check before you load the image into the bitmap. As for what's wrong with your code, well you don't seek back to the beginning of the stream before you read from it. Hence Read returns zero, which you don't check.

Comment: Just in case my first sentence was too cryptic, when you save a bitmap, you'll get a BMP file. You won't get a png. You won't get a jpeg. You won't get a gif.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the problem here is that when I click on the image it gives me a file dialog to chose for one, and then it triggers onChange event, so I can't "see" what type of image user actually selected and I need that information. (even better if I could get image path)

Comment: Then check that before treating it as a TBitmap at all. Likewise instead of just giving back `'?'` you could come up with details, such as the 8 bytes you read and maybe even `MS.Position`.

Comment: You could just read TImage.Picture.Graphic.ClassType.ClassName

Comment: @DejanDozet you need to get that information from the file dialog, not from the TImage. Especially the file path. That is lost once you load a new file into the TImage, so you need to save the path somewhere you can use it later.

Comment: @RenateSchaaf you don't need the `ClassName` or the `ClassType` (BTW, you can get to the `ClassName` without going through the `ClassType`). You can type-check the `Graphic` itself instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks. I've just found an event onLoaded which has FileName and that is all that I need (I am using TImageControl).

Comment: FYI, FMX's `TBitmap` is not limited to BMP images, but its `SaveToStream()` method saves in PNG format only. To save in other formats, you need to use `TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToStream()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I didn't know that the `TImageControl` has an `OnLoaded` event with a `const FileName: string` argument, that is perfect! Can't be better!

Comment: We thought you were using VCL's `TImage`, not FMX's `TImageControl`. Next time, please be more specific about the frameworks and controls you are actually using.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, it was the last thing on my mind to confuse you, believe me. So is there any TImageControl in VCL?

Comment: VCL has `TImage`, not `TImageControl`. Different controls, different functionalities.

Comment: Indeed, VCL is to FMX as cars are to airplanes.